# Add multiple classpath entries to scala REPL classpath

Tags: scala, classpath, read-eval-print-loop

:cp seems to only accept a single entry

```
scala> :cp /usr/lib/hadoop/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/*:/usr/lib/hbase/*:/usr/lib/hbase/lib/*:
/home/sboesch/spark-master/lib_managed/jars/*:/home/sboesch/spark-master/lib_managed/bundles/*:

The path '/usr/lib/hadoop/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/*:/usr/lib/hbase/*:/usr/lib/hbase/lib/*:/home/sboesch/spark-master/lib_managed/jars/*:/home/sboesch/spark-master/lib_managed/bundles/*:' 
doesn't seem to exist.
```

Any thoughts on how to do this *when already in the REPL*.  Yes I know how to set it up from *outside the REPL* :

```
CLASSPATH=/usr/lib/hadoop/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/*:/usr/lib/hbase/*:/usr/lib/hbase/lib/*
:/home/sboesch/spark-master/lib_managed/jars/*:
/home/sboesch/spark-master/lib_managed/bundles/*:  scala
```

**EDIT**  It seems the intent were not clear.  I am working on code in the REPL. Then have a new snippet of code that requires a few classpath entries. It is a ONE OFF affair: so I do not want to add to build.sbt or to the scala/lib dir , etc.  I did not receive any answer really satisifying this use case, but awarded the best efforts anyways.

Comment: I'm pretty sure :cp is broken in recent versions and awaits a fix. FYI. But that's an obvious use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and dirty approach, add a link from $SCALA_HOME/lib/ to a folder with additional jar files. Then from REPL you can import packages of interest.

Answer (score 3):

scala -cp "path1:path2" now seems to work.

> scala -version Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xms512m -Xmx4096m
>   -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=1024m; support
>   was removed in 8.0  Scala code runner version 2.11.8 -- Copyright
>   2002-2016, LAMP/EPFL

Answer (score 2):

The help text for `:cp` says:

```
:cp <path>               add a jar or directory to the classpath
```

So I'm guessing there's no exact way for you to get that. I'd use this:

```
:load <path>             interpret lines in a file
```

I confirmed that it works for REPL commands as well as Scala code.

**Addendum:**

If you use SBT then all your projects dependencies are in the class-path for the REPL launched by SBT's `console` task.

Comment: We are unfortunately relying on external files here. I will await to see if any other solutions.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by “external files” or why they would make `:load` unsuitable.

Comment: Setting up external artifacts - including files - was against the intent of the answer. But in any case i appreciate the input, will give you an upvote.

Comment: Thanks. But is it really easier to type or copy and paste the classpath into the REPL every time? I added an alternative to my answer.

Comment: I updated the OP since it seems the intent were not clear enough.